# Using imports conditionally without import()

Tags: javascript, import, module

This may sound weird but I need to use imports in a conditional way and without using `await import()` .

Here's a quick example, lets say I have this code:

```
import { en } from './langs/en.json';
import { fr } from './langs/fr.json';
```

And I want to conditionally use `en` or `fr`.
Something like:

```
const selectedLang = "en";
const lang = global[selectedLang];
```

Is there a way of doing so?
I know that under the browser all global variables are stored in the `window` object.
But it is not the case with this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use plain old `require` for this:

```
const selectedLang = "en";
const lang = require(`./langs/${selectedLang}.json`);
```

Comment: This would work!